# Need help to find only unique pairs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following (and I assume easy) issue: My spreadsheet contains two columns, I want to find the combination where the value in A only has B = I0001 but no other status.

As you can see in the example given below, the values in A can have I0001 but also other statuses. I need to find those "As" that only have I0001 (e.g.  NPBA000549C01P I0001)

See this table:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just setting a filter on B? Or concatenate A & B and set a filter on that column

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of info when possible. Please post your table data directly in the question.

Comment: It's still plain text that could be easily represented directly in the question.

Comment: @B001ᛦ Pasting text or data as an image makes it much more difficult to replicate on our own machines to build a formula or VBA that would help OP solve the issue. Pasting as a picture causes us to have to toggle between two browser windows. Data and text should be dropped in and formatted as code. A site like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ can help format excel data nicely for SO questions.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the below formula in column C and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$28,A1)=1,$B$2:$B$28="I0001")=TRUE,"Unique Combination",""),"")
```

**Results:**

[image]